# Taking a long string of numbers and removing any zeroes in front of it, then returning that altered string (in Java)

Tags: java, string

So I have a public static method 'getWithoutLeadingZeroes', which gets passed a String and simply needs to return it without any zeroes prefixing the string of numbers.

Now, I know that I need to iterate through the string until I find the first non-zero char in the string, but I'm not exactly sure how to take the point where the method finds the non-zero char and start copying the remainder of the String into a new String, then returning it.

Here's what I have so far:

```
public static String getWithoutLeadingZeroes(String s) {

    boolean notZero = false;

    char[] t = new char[x];

    for(int i = 0; i<s.length(); i++){

            if(s.charAt(i) == 0){

                notZero = false;

            } else {

                notZero = true; 

            }
    if(notZero = true){

        for(int j = index.charAt(i))

    }

    return ""; //to be completed
}
```

I created a boolean variable to stop the loop once it hits the non-zero char and I'm pretty positive the first half of the code is accurate, but its the creating of the new String to be returned that I'm a bit stuck on. Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: You want `s.charAt(i) == '0'`, not `s.charAt(i) == 0`.  0 is the NUL character not the character '0'.

Comment: Try `s.replaceFirst("^0+", "")`.

Answer (score 0):

You are NOT stopping your loop.

You could do that using the *break* keyword.

And: your comparison is wrong, it should read

```
if (... == '0'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`String#substring(int beginIndex)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring-int-) instead:

```
public static String getWithoutLeadingZeroes(String s) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < s.length() && s.charAt(i) == '0') i++;
    return s.substring(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the following way?

```
public static String getWithoutLeadingZeroes(String s) {
   while(s.startsWith('0'))
      s = s.substring(1);
   return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative solution:

```
public String getWithoutLeadingZeroes(String str) {
     int from = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
          if(str.charAt(i) == '0'){
             from = i;
          }else{
             break;
          }
     }
     return str.substring(from+1);
}
```

You can then make it a little bit more robust by implementing `try/catch` blocks and possibly along with cases that deal with unexpected input e.g `null` parameter or a zero-length string etc.

Comment: So would that entail adding additional if/else statements to deal with those cases? I'm not familiar with try/catch blocks, but I take that using them would allow me to deal with those unexpected inputs?

Comment: @MaxUjhazy yeah so basically, first option is you can either add addition if statements just before the "int from = 0" and do something like if(str==null) return "empty string";  etc. the best option though would be to encapsulate the entire code within the method with try/catch and basically what that means is if an incorrect input is passed to the method as a parameter it will be caught by the catch handler and you can handle it there.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution.

```
public static String getWithoutLeadingZeroes(String stringOfNumbers) {
    return String.valueOf(Long.parseLong(stringOfNumbers));
}
```

Comment: This would cover most of it, except for a null string of numbers. What would cover that case?

Comment: Just check the variable first if it is empty or null. Or you can use Apache's NumberUtils toLong http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/math/NumberUtils.html#toLong%28java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
String nmbrStr = "1001234";
String cleanedStr = nmbrStr; // this way the whole number will be
                                // returned if in has no leading zeroes

for (int i = 0; i < nmbrStr.length(); i++) {

    if (nmbrStr.charAt(i) != '0') {
        cleanedStr = nmbrStr.substring(i);
        break;
    }
}

System.out.println(cleanedStr);
```

You can also use `Integer.parseInt(nmbrStr)` which is a lot cleaner